# Angular 5, too much work

Tags: angular, angular5

I just started to learn Angular 2/4/5 after working quite some time with AngularJS.
I found out Angular 5 to be much more complex (for me).
Here is what happened:

I wanted to create a CRUD for User. What I did is:

1. Created **app-routing.module.ts**
2. Created 4 components for Create, View, Edit, List
3. Added 4 imports for above 4 components in app-routing.module.ts

   ```
   import { UserCreateComponent } from 'app/components/user/create/create.component';
   import { UserEditComponent } from 'app/components/user/edit/edit.component';
   import { UserListComponent } from 'app/components/user/list/list.component';
   import { UserViewComponent } from 'app/components/user/view/view.component';
   ```
4. Added 4 paths in  in app-routing.module.ts:

   ```
   path: 'user/list',
   component: UserListComponent

   path: 'user/create',
   component: UserCreateComponent

   path: 'user/view/:id',
   component: UserViewComponent

   path: 'user/edit/:id',
   component: UserEditComponent
   ```
5. Imported above 4 components again in app.module.ts:

   ```
   import { UserCreateComponent } from 'app/components/user/create/create.component';
   import { UserEditComponent } from 'app/components/user/edit/edit.component';
   import { UserListComponent } from 'app/components/user/list/list.component';
   import { UserViewComponent } from 'app/components/user/view/view.component';
   ```
6. Added following in **declarations** section:

   ```
   UserEditComponent,
   UserListComponent,
   UserViewComponent,
   UserCreateComponent,
   ```

Is there a better way of doing, I feel its way more complex and duplicate.

Comment: I don't see why that's different from AngularJS. The only thing that you might simplify is that the creating and editing forms, usually are the very similar or the same, so you can re-use the same component

Comment: I see nothing complex about that. If these are totally different components, there should be 4 of them. Otherwise some of them (at least Edit and Create) could be refactored to a single component.

Comment: This is done with a similar amount of work as AngularJS. Not sure where this being too much more work comes in because it really isn't.

Comment: I will add that the view component also can be the same as create and edit with only a form.disable(). 
The Angular is a lot about reusability of the components, if you choose wisely what components should be dumb or smart, your application could be very easy to maintain and improve. (by easy I also mean fast)

Comment: Don't write everything by hand, though. Simplify your life with [Angular-CLI](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli) to generate your components, services, etc.

Comment: Hmmm, seems I'm going the right way, components needs to be specified both in router and app.component

Answer (score 1):

You could try **lazy loading**, which loads the component only when a specific routing module is called.
Otherwise your code is correct and is also the basic way to do routing in Angular.

Answer (score 1):

That's the way of doing things in Angular2. An Angular Application is nothing more than a tree of Components. At the root of that tree, the top level Component will be rendered when booting the app.

Because the components are structured in a parent/child tree, when each Component renders, it recursively renders its children Components.

So each component should have its component class (.ts) and template and should also belong to a module. Finally, a component must be imported before using it. The idea with import is a lot like import in Java or require in Ruby: we’re pulling in these dependencies from another module and making these dependencies available for use in this file.

Answer (score 0):

@Ashutosh, There are several options, e.g. you can reduce your component to only two, UserListComponent and UserEditComponent (even you can have only one). Then, in ngOnInit check about ActivatedRoute or router

```
  constructor(private router: Router, private activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute)

  status:number
  ngOnInit()
  {
      if (this.router.url.indexOf("create")>=0)
      {
          status=0;
      }
      else
      {
          this.activatedRoute.paramMap.subscribe((params: ParamMap) =>
          { 
              console.log(params.get('id'))
              if (this.router.url.indexOf("view")>=0)
                 status=1;
              if (this.router.url.indexOf("edit")>=0)
                status=2;
          })
      }
  }
```

Comment: Hmmm, will make code look more complex, will check this in such situation, thanks